# How can I host my NodeJS app "forever" without my computer being on?

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, cpanel

On my website, I host an express app that hosts a different port than what is hosted by Namecheap, which is what I am using for hosting. Right now I'm just hosting the express app in the terminal in cPanel for testing, but when I release the site this way won't be acceptable.

Is there a way I could host my express app without my computer always being on and hosting it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pm2 as global dependency in your hosting server.

```
npm i pm2 -g
```

After that go to app directory and run.

```
pm2 start app.js --name "name of your app"
```

It will run your application forever until some error may not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a docker image of your app and run the docker container forever or use process managers like pm2 or forever to run your app in detached mode.